# What happens to the Ram in Leviticus 16:3?

Tags: torah-study

In [Leviticus 16:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.16.3?lang=bi&aliyot=0), Aaron is told to bring a bull for sin offering, and a ram for burnt offering. He is later told in [verse 5](https://www.sefaria.org/Leviticus.16.5?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) to bring two male goats for sin offering and from what I see yet another ram for burnt offering. Throughout chapter 16, he is then given detailed instruction with regards to the bull and the two male goats. But he's not given detailed instructions about what to do with the ram(s). What's going on here?

Comment: דאיל המוספים הנאמר בפ' פינחס בקרבנות יוהכ"פ הוא הוא האיל הזה

Comment: @rosends Can you write in English? My Hebrew is not that good :D

Comment: that ram was part of the Musaf sacrifices as listed in Parshat Pinchas.